# Preprocessor Directives

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, debugging

Is there a simplistic reference for all preprocessor directives?

Answer (score 4):

For C#:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The C# compiler doesn't have a preprocessor in the traditional sense, but it does support a limited number of preprocessor like commands #define, #if and so forth, but you will not be able to do the same stunts that e.g. a C/C++ preprocessor can do.

EDIT: While typing other have supplied lists of supported options. Thumbs up.